# Cannot retrieve GM_CODE from geojson file

Tags: d3.js

After looking at ["Let's make a map"](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/map/) (nice tutorial!) i decided to make a map of our province and color all the municipality's of that province. I did the work on shapefiles and succeded in the projection of the whole province in black. Can you help to understand the svg.selectAll(".subunit") function so i can alter it to extract the GM_CODE from my geojson file? If needed i can send the geojson file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<style>
.GM_CODE.GM0003 { fill: #ddc; }
.GM_CODE.GM0005 { fill: #cdd; }
.GM_CODE.GM0007 { fill: #cdc; }
.GM_CODE.GM0009 { fill: #dcd; }

</style>
<body>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://d3js.org/topojson.v1.min.js"></script>
<script>

var width = 960,
    height = 640;

var projection = d3.geo.albers()
    .center([0, 53.2])
    .rotate([-6.5, 0])
    .parallels([50, 60])
    .scale(40000)
    .translate([width / 2, height / 2]);

var path = d3.geo.path()
    .projection(projection);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

d3.json("groningen.json", function(error, json) {
  svg.selectAll(".subunit")
        .data(topojson.feature(json, json.objects.gemeente).features)
    .enter.append("path")
      .attr("class", function(d) { return "GM_CODE " + d.GM_CODE; })
      .attr("d", path);
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if you are using a GeoJSON file, you should use the features directly.

```
svg.selectAll('.subunits')
    .data(json.features)
    .enter()
    .append('path')
    .attr('class', function(d) { return 'GM_CODE ' + d.properties.GM_CODE; })
    .attr('d', path);
```

Assuming that your features have the attribute have the property `GM_CODE`, you can assign the class `GM_CODE` and `GM0003` (for instance) with this code. If you add a sample of your GeoJSON file I can update the exact code here.